# Visio 2016 "Data Refresh" resets all of Data Graphics every time I refresh the linked Excel file

Tags: visio

When I use the "Refresh All" feature in Visio 2016 (which is linked to an external Excel document that has my org chart info in it), it resets all of my Data Graphic inputs that I setup.

I have to regularly "Refresh All" in the Visio file since we have an active org chart, but doing so resets all my Data Graphics inputs - which forces me to reinput them EVERY. SINGLE. TIME. Super time consuming and frustrating.

Is this a bug or a setting that can be fixed?

I was expecting that my Data Graphics inputs would remain saved and not reset everything I refresh my data.

Comment: Your Question suggests a display of values attached to nodes of an organization chart.  If that's the idea, based on what you wrote, the chart potentially could have changed completely from the last refresh to the new one.  So the need to reinput all data values is connected to a potential loss of all the old chart nodes.  More context is needed to understand what if anything one can save.

Comment: I'm simply trying to understand why a simply refresh can't just update the numbers instead of altogether resetting all the established settings.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing only from a single data source (the Excel spreadsheet) instead of all data sources.  See the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-imported-data-ab3668a1-873d-4109-8fa2-532670bc01e2).  Or is the Excel spreadsheet your only data source?  Your post suggests that the spreadsheet is only one of several data sources.

Comment: Correct - only one source, which is an Excel doc